# Won't subclass across modules/frameworks in Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift

This code works great when in the same source file:

```
class SuperClass {
  func sayHello() {
    print("Hello")
  }
}

class MyClass: SuperClass {
}
```

I now move the 'SuperClass' class to another source file in a 'MyFramework' embedded framework, and set access control to public:

```
public class SuperClass {
  public func sayHello() {
    print("Hello")
  }
}
```

The app source file:

```
import MyFramework

class MyClass: SuperClass {
}
```

However I get a "Use of undeclared type 'SuperClass'" error.

The "MyFramework" framework must be recognised as the import statement doesn't cause an error (e.g. I don't get a "No such module 'MyFramework'" error).

If I change the app source file to this:

```
import MyFramework

class MyClass: MyFramework.SuperClass {
}
```

...then I get a "No type named 'SuperClass' in 'MyFramework'"

It's worth mentioning that the relevant source file in MyFramework DOES have the box in the Target Membership section checked (for MyFramework, not MyFrameworkTests).

MyFramework is added in the 'Linked Framework and Libraries' section.

I've tried a clean build and also tried the example above in a new, empty project, but I get the same problems.

How do you subclass across modules/frameworks?

Comment: Are you trying create a framework for another use? With Swift I just use a public struct and it works any where in the project or I use just classname().funcname() and no import required.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?  Seeing the same issue.

Comment: Maybe change public to open?

Comment: I am also facing this problem and is there any solution? Any help?